# extract only required data from array php

Tags: php, arrays

I am using an API and it returns large data of array, but i need only certain items from that array and unset others, how that can be done?

Here is my array formate

I need DIGS,EXP and GI only and unset other items form array, How can this be done from large array? is there any quick way to do this?

Below is the array which i get from the API

https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist

```
  Array
(
    [DIGS] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 12192
            [Url] => /coins/digs/overview
            [ImageUrl] => /media/20706/digs.png
            [Name] => DIGS
            [CoinName] => Diggits
            [FullName] => Diggits (DIGS)
            [Algorithm] => Scrypt
            [ProofType] => PoS
            [FullyPremined] => 1
            [TotalCoinSupply] => 100000000
            [PreMinedValue] => N/A
            [TotalCoinsFreeFloat] => N/A
            [SortOrder] => 464
        )

    [EXP] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 12194
            [Url] => /coins/exp/overview
            [ImageUrl] => /media/20707/exp.png
            [Name] => EXP
            [CoinName] => Expanse
            [FullName] => Expanse (EXP)
            [Algorithm] => Ethash
            [ProofType] => PoW
            [FullyPremined] => 0
            [TotalCoinSupply] => N/A
            [PreMinedValue] => N/A
            [TotalCoinsFreeFloat] => N/A
            [SortOrder] => 465
        )

    [GCR] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 12217
            [Url] => /coins/gcr/overview
            [ImageUrl] => /media/20708/gcr.png
            [Name] => GCR
            [CoinName] => Global Currency Reserve
            [FullName] => Global Currency Reserve (GCR)
            [Algorithm] => N/A
            [ProofType] => PoS
            [FullyPremined] => 0
            [TotalCoinSupply] => 0
            [PreMinedValue] => N/A
            [TotalCoinsFreeFloat] => N/A
            [SortOrder] => 466
        )

    [MAPC] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 12223
            [Url] => /coins/mapc/overview
            [ImageUrl] => /media/20710/mapc.png
            [Name] => MAPC
            [CoinName] => MapCoin
            [FullName] => MapCoin (MAPC)
            [Algorithm] => X11
            [ProofType] => PoS
            [FullyPremined] => 0
            [TotalCoinSupply] => 2228921.184
            [PreMinedValue] => N/A
            [TotalCoinsFreeFloat] => N/A
            [SortOrder] => 467
        )

    [MI] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 12225
            [Url] => /coins/mi/overview
            [ImageUrl] => /media/20711/mi.png
            [Name] => MI
            [CoinName] => XiaoMiCoin
            [FullName] => XiaoMiCoin (MI)
            [Algorithm] => Scrypt
            [ProofType] => PoW/PoS
            [FullyPremined] => 0
            [TotalCoinSupply] => 400000000
            [PreMinedValue] => N/A
            [TotalCoinsFreeFloat] => N/A
            [SortOrder] => 468
        )

    [CON] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 12985
            [Url] => /coins/con_/overview
            [ImageUrl] => /media/20717/con_.png
            [Name] => CON_
            [CoinName] => Paycon
            [FullName] => Paycon (CON_)
            [Algorithm] => X13
            [ProofType] => PoW/PoS
            [FullyPremined] => 0
            [TotalCoinSupply] => 50000000
            [PreMinedValue] => N/A
            [TotalCoinsFreeFloat] => N/A
            [SortOrder] => 469
        )
)

Tried Code below:

 $data_url = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/';
  $data_json = cp_get_url_data_curl($data_url);
  $data_all_currencies_raw = json_decode($data_json, true);
  $data_all_currencies = $data_all_currencies_raw['Data'];


$search = ["SUB","USC"];



array_walk($data_all_currencies, function(&$item, $key) use($search){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($item); 
  if(!in_array($key, $search)){

     unset($item);
  }
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data_all_currencies);  
exit;
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Quick way : use `where` clause in query

Comment: This isn't an array the `stdClass Object` tells you that its an object, so you use object notation to access the different properties

Comment: i am getting result via URL - https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the `MAPC`, `MI` & `CON` objects, you can loop through the main object in `Object['Data']` while having `if clauses` for the Objects that you want.

E.g (going to use C# so you have an idea of what to do)

I assume that you are retrieveing some sort of JSON or XML file, if so, and if you deserialize it properly you can use it as a dictionary. 
Something along the lines of:

```
foreach( var subObjectData in Object['Data'] ){
     if(subObjectData['MAPC']){
          //Do something
     }else if(subObjectData['MI']){
          //Do something else
     }else{
          //Destroy unneeded objects
     }

     //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you should convert your object to array. and then apply following code over it to fetch required data only.

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($array), true);
$search = ["MPC","CON","GI"];
array_walk($array['data'], function(&$item, $key) use($search){
  if(!in_array($key, $search)){
     unset($item);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why convert to an array? This is certainly doable with an stdObject

Comment: Sorry mate... I don't know that way.. So posted this

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, I was more asking if there was any added benefits to doing it this way

Comment: I don't know about benifit. But yeah. I used to do such things this way... Because array walk wont accept objects